# How to install and start a windows service on a VMWare virtual machine for Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have created a Windows Service in visual studios 2015, and want to use a virtual machine running windows 10 to test it. However, I am having trouble installing the service. I have enabled share file and shared the file containing my service executable, but when I try to use the command line to install it, it doesn't seem to work. I can't use the visual studios developer command prompt since it is not installed on my VM. Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: _" have enabled share file and shared the file containing my service executable"_ - I suspect Windows may not want to install a service when the exe file is on another computer. Why don't you copy it to the VM?

Comment: Clearly Windows is not going to install a service that is physically located on another computer (which is anywhere outside the VM). Copy it into the VM, and then install it like you would any other service. And *it doesn't seem to work* is not a problem description.

Comment: @stuartd I was under the impression that enabling share file and choosing the specific file does copy the file to the VM since the file then appears in the files on the virtual machine. Is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without  visual studio developer command prompt.

**Technically those are the steps:**

1. connect to your VM and open CMD.
2. navigate to folder destination where the EXE of your service is found.
    for example: `cd C:\Users\XXX\YYY\bin\Release`
3. install the service using that command (check your .net framework version in the VM): `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil yourservicename.exe`
4. probably you will need give permissions to the release (or whatever folder you have).
    the permissions is for `LOCAL SERVICE` and `NETWORK SERVICE` groups:
    **right click on the release folder>>properties>>security tab>>Edit button >>Add button >>search for LOCAL SERVICE and NETWORK SERVICE using the Check Names button and finally allow those groups full control Permission.**
5. start the service via task manager>>services

Comment: This worked, but my main problem ended up being that I was not a local administrator, Thanks.